# How to deal with Unicode usernames in Windows 8

Tags: unicode, fonts

Recently I noticed that a user name was blocked on my web service because it didn't match the regular expression filter that I had placed there to restrict character to letters, numbers and certain symbols. The string was Ｄｏｎｇ and it turns out that in my game a user must have pasted a Unicode string into the text entry field, something I hadn't considered up to that point.

I did a bit of research and noted that C# Regex is Unicode aware and I can add \p{L}\p{M}\p{Z}\p{N} in order to allow more combinations in but I still wouldn't be sure that I allowed or disallowed all appropriate combinations. Particularly I wanted to be able to block certain words from being used that might offend younger players (or older ones too). Right now I have a bad word filter that I apply after the user completes entry which does a good job of blocking most attempts at making a username that is offensive but only (as I realize now) if they used ASCII to compose it.

How do other games deal with this given that certain Unicode characters aren't represented in the particular font that is chosen for the game and that certain Unicode combinations can actually muck up the alignment in your display?

Comment: It is pretty unclear how you expect to use Regex to do a dictionary lookup.  As is filtering swear words from a language you don't know.  Just allow users to file a complaint.

Comment: I wasn't using Regex as a dictionary lookup, rather as a test to make sure that data coming into the web service was what I expected. Essentially the string Ｄｏｎｇ passed the local bad word filter(because I erroneously assumed the characters would be ASCII) but then failed when it was passed to the web service.     So you feel that simply allowing all characters through and waiting for users to complain would be the best approach?

Comment: Unless you want to learn how to swear in Chinese, Korean, Vietnamese, Swahili, etcetera, yes.

Comment: Fair enough :) But as I said, certain Unicode characters are non-existant in the fontset I am using (Segoe UI) and more worrisome is that certain combinations of Unicode characters alter the alignment and position of the text apparently. If they dont exist then they show up as squares I imagine but the ones that alter positioning could mess up the leaderboard display or other elements in my game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more quality games / apps use a fallback font for characters their main font don't support - so fallback on Arial Unicode if Segoe UI doesn't have that character.  This usually works fine since it's just the non-English characters, emoji, and whatnot that end up rendered using the alternate font.

If you don't do that, you have to restrict user input to what your chosen fonts will support, if not all the way back to ASCII.

The question of supported fonts compared to restricting "bad words" is totally separate, though.  Having a flagging mechanism is a good idea but also using a common list of "naughty words" can be helpful as well.  Even if you don't speak every language you can probably find word lists for those languages on the web somewhere.

Comment: Yes, back when I asked the question I erroneously mixed the two situations(Unicode font support/bad word filtering). Is there a method to detect which characters are not represented in a font other than visual inspection?

Comment: It depends on your font library.  If there's no explicit support for fallbacks or checking for characters, you can probably ask for the size of a glyph, if it's width or height is <= 0 then it's not present in the font.